# IP mask to EC2 IPV4 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I host a service on AWS. It provides me the IP and the ports available, for example, `17.100.100.100:8080`. How do I assign a domain to it? Is it possible to do it on AWS itself?

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) to host a domain and configure resource records to point at your IP address.

1. First, [register the domain](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/get-a-domain/) using Route 53 or any other DNS registrar.
2. Next, configure a [hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-working-with.html) for your domain in Route 53.
3. Then, allocate an [Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) and associate it with your EC2 instance (assuming you're using EC2).
4. Finally, [configure a DNS A record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html) in your hosted zone that points your preferred name at the elastic IP address.